# Blacklisted by Google - Deceptive site ahead

Tags: php, server

Let's say, I have a primary domain, and a few add-on domains on a Cpanel share hosting, and every add-on domain has its own sub-domain goes like sub-domain.primary-domain.com. The add-on domains are all real sites and public, and the primary domain is just for the hosting account, `http://primary-domain.com` is actually only one page with a logo.

Bad thing happened a few days ago, primary-domain.com got blocked by Chrome and Firefox: Deceptive site ahead!

Good things are: All add-on domains are fine for now.

Under Google webmastertools, warning came out as below:

These pages attempt to trick users into doing something dangerous such as installing unwanted software or revealing personal information.

Sample URL(warning for harmful content):

```
one-of-sub-domain.primary_domain.com/login.php/magmi/web/download_file.php
```

I have no idea what `./login.php/magmi/web/download_file.php` does and how it does, I do have a file `/login.php`, but I could not find `magmi/web/download_file.php` through the whole server, however I did see it appeared on my visitor log coming from a IP from India. Even it is hidden somewhere, but how can it be executed behind /login.php/?

Funny thing is that the add-on domain comes along with the above sub-domain has not been blacklisted, but they are using exactly the same directory.

I asked my hosting to scan the whole root, result showed clean and found no targeted URL and 0 malware hit, hosting checked my primary_domain.com on McAfee, results green with minimum risk same as the ratio Google and Yahoo have. I restored the whole directory with the version which has been good for long time, and asked Google for a review. The result came back pretty soon, still the same, nothing changed.

I do not worry about the primary domain quite much as it is actually not a site, but I guess it won't be too long the related add-on domain will get blocked.

Any idea about this hack? I did see some search result about `magmi/web/download_file.php`, but I have no experience about it. Would it be possible that the hacker changed some directives on the server that triggering some redirection? All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us the domain name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Deceptive site ahead" on google chrome and malicious code can not be isolated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132012/deceptive-site-ahead-on-google-chrome-and-malicious-code-can-not-be-isolated)

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through Google and found the the problem is from an exploit using the plugin uploader in an eccomerce webapp. The attacker is essencially able the upload a php file using the site's mass uploader script that converts the file to zip and then installs it onto the server.

https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/35052/

I would first start looking for the site that is hosting the magento site and scan it for the problem direcrory. Then take the appropriate steps to eradicate it. The disable the software's ability to upload plugin through the Web interface and make them upload the plugin they want manually through sftp.

Next step is to change all the passwords to everything across everybody's accounts just in case the attacker was able to glean that intel.

---------------------------@link-exploit

Exploit found date:  10/24/2014
Security Researcher name:  Parvinder.       Bhasin
Contact info:  parvinder.bhasin@gmail.com
twitter:  @parvinderb - scorpio

Currently tested version:
Magento version:  Magento CE - 1.8 older
MAGMI version: v0.7.17a older

Download software link:
Magento server:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/download
MAGMI Plugin:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/files/magmi-0.7/plugins/packages/

MAGMI (MAGento Mass Importer) suffers from File inclusion vulnerability
(RFI) which allows an attacker to upload essentially any PHP file (without
any sanity checks).  This PHP file could then be used to skim credit card
data, rewrite files, run remote commands, delete files..etc.  Essentially,
this gives attacker ability to execute remote commands on the vulnerable
server.

Steps to reproduce:

1. http:///magmi/web/magmi.php
2. Under upload new plugins:
   click on "choose file"
   MAGento plugins are basically php file zipped.  So create a php shell and
   zip the file. ex: evil.php  ex: zip file: evil_plugin.zip.  After the file
   has been uploaded, it will say:  Plugin packaged installed.
   evil.php:
3. Your malicious evil.php file is extracted now.  All you then need to do
   is just access the evil.php page from:
   http:///magmi/plugins/evil.php
   At this point you could really have access to the entire system.  Download
   any malware, install rootkits, skim credit card data ..etc.etc.

Comment: Thanks a million to Jonathan for the response. Very valuable information provided. I will definitely look into that case to see what happened.